# Magento - Calculated Product Attribute (property)

Tags: magento

I would like to add a calculated attribute (property) to Products. It's value is to be calculated using a PHP function eg:

```
function CalculateCustomAttribute() {
  ...
  //Do some calculations based on other Product attributes, date, etc 
  ...
  return $calculatedValue; // type float
}
```

This calculated attribute needs to be:

- displayed in the Product page,
- filterable through the "Layered Navigation", and
- sortable in the "Product Listing".

Could this be done? And how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do might be possible, but I am not sure that the approach you have described would be doable, I think it is too simplistic to work with the very complex Magento platform.

I had a similar project where the actual price of the products was constantly changing based on a few inputs and I was able to solve the problem fairly well, but it was definitely more complicated thank what you seem to be hoping for.  I am not sure this scenario is helpful to you or not, but here it goes...

The basic idea was that I created new product attributes (eav attributes).  These served as the inputs to determine what the price really should be.  Note that in my case, these attributes were being updated fairly regularly by an outside process.

Then I created an observer on the "catalog_product_save_before" event that would simply do something like this:

```
//some calculations to get the $newPrice
$product->setPrice($newPrice);
```

So basically that will make it so that the price field will always be current whenever you save a product in the administrative screens.

Then also, since several of the attributes that were used as inputs were constantly changing (updated by an outside process), so we also had to add a magento cron job to run every so often, and it would recalculate the price for all the affected products with something like this...

```
//some calculations to get the $newPrice
$product->addAttributeUpdate("price", $newPrice, Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId());
```

So it all boils down to the fact that you should have the attribute saved in the db.  And of course you need to find the specific spots of where to update that derived attribute.  Maybe your requirements will vary slightly from what I have described, but it might get you on the right path at least.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'm trying to eliminate the need of using observers and a cron job to update the field. If the Calculated Attributes idea is not possible, then your suggestion would a good work around. Let's see if somebody knows if and how Calculated Attributes could be achieved.

Comment: The real challenge is getting the layered navigation and sortable listings to work without a field in the db.  It probably can be done, but I imagine it will be a mucketty solution.  Best of luck.

Comment: Yes, you're right - layered navigation and list sorting seem to require DB fields due to the paging.

Comment: This leads me to the following question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235518/magento-product-attribute-which-is-not-visible-editable-in-administration)