# Magento - Product Attribute which is not visible/editable in administration

Tags: magento

Is it possible in code (or manually) to create a Product Attribute that is not visible (and thus not editable) through the administration edit product page? And how?

(The attribute only needs to used (save / load) in php modules)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. If you doing it in install script - you should set `'visible'` to false:

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, '<attribute_code>', array(
    ...
    'visible'       => false,
    ...
));
```

If you need change it for existent attribute directly in db - go to `catalog_eav_attribute` table, find your attribute (look for attribute id by attribute code in `eav_attribute` table) and set it's `is_visible` field to 0.

Comment: Are you sure is_visible field is available in eav_attribute table ? I am talking about Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 .Because I can get only these fields (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`)