# magento product attributes and removing them from backend

Tags: magento

I want a hidden attribute, or completely not there in backend for some attributes im using to tie to a special product type I created.

I believe I need the attribute assigned to the attribute set in order to be able to use it.. but correct me if I am wrong!

Now that I think about this, I am probably doing this wrong.  There is probably a way to add an attribute to PRODUCT_TYPE (my custom product type is "voucher") instead of PRODUCT.

Not sure though.. Hints?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe I need the attribute assigned to the attribute set in order to be able to use it

Your attribute needs to be assigned to an attribute set *if you want to be able to edit/view the attribute in the Magento Admin area*. It sounds like you do not want your attribute visible there, so the simple solution is to: create your attribute without assigning it to an attribute set. You can still assign/edit/view your attribute through database manipulation or by loading the product model and using the [magic get & set methods](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento#5).

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setFoo('hidden attribute value');
echo $product->getFoo();
```

Comment: does that really work? interesting.  I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Yep, it really works. However, as soon as someone adds that attribute to an attribute set it's going to become visible in those product listings, so if this is a security issue then I would advise against using this method. If you simply want to prevent the casual user from editing an attribute then this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the visibility of your attributes by database, have a look here:

[Magento - Product Attribute which is not visible/editable in administration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235518/magento-product-attribute-which-is-not-visible-editable-in-administration)

You can also lock attributes and make them readonly for your backend users by using a observer:

[Magento read-only and hidden product attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384120/magento-read-only-and-hidden-product-attributes)